# How do I "scanf()" and "printf()" a user's message in discord.js when creating a BOT for Discord server?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am new at coding and I only have the basic knowledge of `C` but I do know how other codes work if I know the functions its equivalent in C. I am using `discord.js` (12.0.2) to make my Discord bot. How do I scan and print a user's sent message?

Answer (score 0):

To 'scan' a user's message, use the `content` property of their message. I barely know C but I'm pretty sure the equivalent of `printf` is `console.log`:

```js
const {Client} = require('discord.js')

const client = new Client()

client.on('message', message => {
  console.log(message.content)
}

client.login(yourToken)
```

I recommend reading the [Discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/).